# Retrieve list values in DWT template

Tags: templating, 2009, dwt

In my package, i have a list of TcmUri which sometimes contains valid TcmUri but also fake TcmUri such as `tcm:0-0-0`.
slideshareList is the name of my list.

I need to write something like this :

```
<!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="slideshareList[${TemplateRepeatIndex}] != 'tcm:0-0-0'" -->
@@RenderComponentPresentation(slideshareList[${TemplateRepeatIndex}],"tcm:125-48340-32")@@ 
<!-- TemplateEndIf -->
```

The TemplateBeginIf does not seem to work because the condition seems to be always verified.
I tried to check what `slideshareList[${TemplateRepeatIndex}]` contains with:

`slideshareList[${TemplateRepeatIndex}]` returns `slideshareList[1]`
`@@slideshareList[${TemplateRepeatIndex}]@@` returns `undefined`

I don't really know what syntax is possible despite my searches on the internet.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: you can try `${String(slideshareList[TemplateRepeatIndex])}`, I have not tested it though. Somthing like that worked for me in the past.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately "undefined" is returned :/

Comment: okay, I'd try different combinations of `@@`, `${` and `string()`. like `String(slideshareList[${TemplateRepeatIndex}])`

Comment: it returns : `String(slideshareList[1])`. Not displaying the real value :/

Comment: Why not fix the TBB that is building your list and make sure you don't add in null URIs, conditions is something which belong in code, and thus in your TBB, not in your layout?

Comment: I needed to add fake tcm in order to be sure I had the right number of tcm in my list. Hard to explain without giving more context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a TBB called Get Linked Components in the Template Base framework for DWT.

You can find it here: https://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/generic-2011-tbbs.aspx.

It will add those nested components to your package that you can easily access without funky DWT hacks.